# How can I add a second addEventListener to a single element

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I am trying to figure out a way to add an eventListener sequential to another. My main goal is to have an image move over to the right, which I was able to get using:

```js
let imageSmall = document.querySelector('.pet-small')

document.getElementsByClassName("pet-small")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(this.classList.contains("active")) {
    this.classList.remove("active");
  }
  else this.classList.add("active");
});
```

The HTML goes as follows

```html
<div class="pet">
    <img class="pet-small" src="https://media.4-paws.org/1/e/d/6/1ed6da75afe37d82757142dc7c6633a532f53a7d/VIER%20PFOTEN_2019-03-15_001-2886x1999-1920x1330.jpg" alt="Our Loyal Companion">
   
    <button class="shrink-grow">Shrink/Grow</button>
  </div>
```

And the CSS I have is

```css
/*style for image*/
.pet-small {
  height:150px;
  transition: 1s;
  

}

.pet-small.active {
    margin-left: 600px;
    transform: rotate3d(360,360,360,360deg);
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to add a second listener to the same image that will take place right after the first one.

I should I remodel the JavaScript or is this a CSS situation? Or is there another way

Comment: You ca just break your logic into two separate functions and call both of them sequentially in the event listener

Comment: You can call `addEventListener()` as many times as you want on the same element, and they'll all run. As the name says, it *adds* listeners, they don't replace.

Comment: And they'll be executed in the same order that you added them.

Comment: So you've successfully added an event listener, and you're asking how to add an event listener?  Did you try... doing it again?

Comment: instead of your `if/else`-statement you could simply use `classList.toggle`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional event listener using `addEventListener` and it will get run after the one you already have. I would not recommend relying on the order of runtime however, so if order matters then you should probably restructure your code such that you don't need multiple event listeners. Generally speaking you want to use a single event listener if the code is related, and 2 event listeners if they have completely different concerns IMO.

A horrible (but functional) way of restructuring code to use a single listener

```js
let imageSmall = document.querySelector('.pet-small');
let cb2 = null;

document.getElementsByClassName("pet-small")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(this.classList.contains("active")) {
    this.classList.remove("active");
  }
  else this.classList.add("active");

  cb2?.();
});

// later on when you want to add the code
cb2 = () => {
    // code here
}
```

in almost every case there will be a better way to restructure your code, I just showed this example as it works in every case.

### Summary

You can simply call `addEventListener` a second time to attach another event listener, however, if order matters, or if they are closely related to each other it probably makes the most sense to restructure your code.

Comment: Thank you! I am still in the intermediate stage of coding/hacking and I am experimenting with different ways to attack projects. I have been looking into different ways to have two eventListeners for a while now but it has just given me a headache.

Comment: This is the codepen of the project where I am having the issue https://codepen.io/bg560581-the-looper/pen/MWGQWyg